# How to disable css minification during development in meteor?

Tags: css, meteor, bundling-and-minification

The meteor docs say that CSS [minification "usually happens" in production](https://guide.meteor.com/build-tool.html#minification). In my project here I had to remove the "standard-minifier-css" package to be able see during development from which css / less files css rules originate.

Any hint on how I have to configure the project that minification only happens for production and the deployed system?

Comment: This isn't really a direct answer to your question, but typically in development for JS and CSS, source maps are used - regardless of minification, dev tools will still show you the relevant code and line number of the LESS file. [Read more](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/readability/source-maps?hl=en)

Comment: Yes, in fact this is a good add-on question: Is it possible to enable source maps in meteot for minification, at least for development?

Comment: I still would be glad if someone could help here :-)

Comment: I would recommend editing, or making a new question, with a more specific focus - rather than ask a broad question, post part of your configuration with examples of what you've tried to change the configuration. Ask specific questions relating to the actual code.